# Python function to modify string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I was asked once to create a function that given a string, remove a few characters from the string.

Is it possible to do this in Python?

This can be done for lists, for example:

```
def poplist(l):
    l.pop()

l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

poplist(l1)
print l1
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

What I want is to do this function for strings.
The only way I can think of doing this is to convert the string to a list, remove the characters and then join it back to a string. But then I would have to return the result.
For example:

```
def popstring(s):
    copys = list(s)
    copys.pop()
    s = ''.join(copys)

s1 = 'abcd'

popstring(s1)

print s1
>>> 'abcd'
```

I understand why this function doesn't work. The question is more if it is possible to do this in Python or not? If it is, can I do it without copying the string?

Comment: Strings are immutable... So **no**.

Comment: Can I create another string, but bind it to the same variable at least?

Comment: Python has no *call by ref*. So again, no.

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM , this would cause problems for cases like `'abca'` , where according to your method, it would return `bc`

Comment: @KaushikNP: oh Ok. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM : One thing you can do, though it will be unnecessarily complicated is by `reversing` the string , remove `one` element, and then `reverse` it back. Like so :                       `s[::-1].replace(s[-1],'',1)[::-1]`

Comment: I am not sure how this would help in my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings are **immutable**, that means you can not **alter the `str` object**. You can of course construct a new string that is some modification of the old string. But you can thus not alter the `s` object in your code.

A workaround could be to **use a container**:

```
class Container:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
```

And then the `popstring` thus is given a contain, it inspect the container, and puts something else into it:

```
def popstring(container):
    container.data = container.data[:-1]

s1 = Container('abcd')
popstring(s1)
```

But again: you did not change the string object itself, you only have put a new string into the container.

You can not perform [*call by reference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) in Python, so you can not call a function:

```
foo(x)
```

and then alter the variable `x`: the reference of `x` is copied, so you can not alter the variable `x` itself.

Comment: This is sort of what I was expecting as a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Strings are `immutable`, so your only main option is to create a `new string` by  `slicing` and `assign` it back.

```
#removing the last char

>>> s = 'abcd'
>>> s = s[:-1]
=> 'abc'
```

Another easy to go method maybe to use `list` and then `join` the elements in it to create your string. Ofcourse, it all **depends on your preference**.

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> ''.join(l)
=> 'abcd'

>>> l.pop()
=> 'd'

>>> ''.join(l)
=> 'abc'
```

---

Incase you are looking to **remove char at a certain index** given by `pos` (index 0 here), you can `slice` the string as :

```
>>> s='abcd'

>>> s = s[:pos] + s[pos+1:]
=> 'abd'
```

Comment: the problem with this is that if you are inside a function you have to return the string, so you have it both as an input parameter and as an output parameter; not exactly elegant; alternatively you could build up a list and convert it to a string at a later point

Answer (score 1):

You could use `bytearray` instead:

```
s1 = bytearray(b'abcd')  # NB: must specify encoding if coming from plain string
s1.pop()     # now, s1 == bytearray(b'abc')
s1.decode()  # returns 'abc'
```

**Caveats**:

- if you plan to filter arbitrary text (i.e. non pure ASCII), this is a **very bad** idea to use `bytearray`
- in this age of concurrency and parallelism, it might be a bad idea to use mutation

By the way, perhaps it is an instance of the `XY problem`. Do you really need to mute strings in the first place?

Comment: This is better than using a list I think. Is it possible to convert it back to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove parts of a strings and assign it to another string:

```
s = 'abc'
s2 = s[1:]
print(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You wont do that.. you can still concatenate but you wont pop until its converted into a list..

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> s+='world'
>>> s
'helloworld'
>>> s.pop()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
>>> list(s).pop()
'd'
>>>
```

But still You can play with **Slicing**

```
>>> s[:-1]
'helloworl'
>>> s[1:]
'elloworld'
>>>
```